# How to Strip out the file extension (.docx, .pdf, etc.) in Oracle while also separating out delimited data from a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am given something like this:
(3 spaces is the delimiter in this case)

```
data_String (Column Name)
C:\Desktop(Filepath)   JSchmoe(username)   FileName.xml
```

I have managed to separate the 3 entities into 3 separate columns. However; I have one last step; I am trying to strip out the ".xml" from the FileName.xml.

I have got the following but it doesn't work:

```
select 
   SUBSTR(SUBSTR(data_String, - instr(reverse(data_String), '   ' + 1)), 
   nullif( instr(SUBSTR(data_String, - instr(reverse(data_String), '   ') + 1), '.', -1) +1, 1) )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to handle file names with no extension? File names that have two dots - like `'REPORT.MARCH2017.PDF'` ?

Comment: I want REPORT.MARCH2017 to show up

Comment: If you do, in fact, have such filenames in your data, you may want to carefully test the various solutions to see if they handle that correctly. (I believe what I posted so far doesn't - I'll check.)

Comment: OK - I edited my Answer to handle that possibility correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4331/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( data_string ) AS
SELECT 'C:\Desktop   JSchmoe   FileName.xml' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - String Functions**:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
         data_string,
         1,
         INSTR( data_string, '   ' )
       ) AS filepath,
       SUBSTR(
         data_string,
         INSTR( data_string, '   ' ) + 3,
         INSTR( data_string, '   ', - 1 ) - INSTR( data_string, '   ' ) - 2
       ) AS name,
       SUBSTR(
         data_string,
         INSTR( data_string, '   ', -1 ) + 3,
         INSTR( data_string, '.', -1 ) - INSTR( data_string, '   ', -1 ) - 3
       ) As filename,
       SUBSTR(
         data_string,
         INSTR( data_string, '.', -1 ) + 1
       ) As extension
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4331/9/0)**:

```
|    FILEPATH |     NAME | FILENAME | EXTENSION |
|-------------|----------|----------|-----------|
| C:\Desktop  | JSchmoe  | FileName |       xml |
```

**Query 2 - Regular Expressions**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( data_string, '^(.+?)   (.+?)   (.+)(\.(.*))?$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS filepath,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( data_string, '^(.+?)   (.+?)   (.+)(\.(.*))?$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 )
         AS name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( data_string, '^(.+?)   (.+?)   (.+)(\.(.*))?$', 1, 1, NULL, 3 )
         AS filename,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( data_string, '^(.+?)   (.+?)   (.+)(\.(.*))?$', 1, 1, NULL, 5 )
         AS extension
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d4331/9/1)**:

```
|   FILEPATH |    NAME | FILENAME | EXTENSION |
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|
| C:\Desktop | JSchmoe | FileName |       xml |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where regexp's come in handy. This removes all letters a-z at the end behind a period char including the period:

```
select regexp_replace(filename,'\.[a-zA-Z]+$') filename_wo_extension
from files;
```

If you want to remove only certain extensions, use:

```
regexp_replace(filename,'\.(docx|pdf|xml)$')
```

To include digits and `-` and `_` as well and limit the max number of chars in an extension to 10:

```
regexp_replace(filename,'\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,10}$')
```

This limit will not change anything in `filename.with.very_long_not_extension` but `.long_ext` at the end will be removed.

Comment: What happens if there are numbers present after period char? Highly unlikely but thinking of any possible scenarios.

Comment: Answer above now.

Comment: I still see the same response. was something changed?

Comment: What if there is a period before the file extension? i.e. (file.name.docx)

Comment: Even then only `.docx` will be removed because of the `$` char at the end which means that a matching pattern, if it exists, should be anchored to the end of the filename. Try removing the `$` to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming some files may have no extension, you need to handle that case as well. It can still be done with INSTR/SUBSTR if you need speed; however, it's easier to write and maintain with regular expressions. Something like:

```
with
  inputs ( data_string ) as (
    select 'C:\Desktop   JSchmoe   FileName.xml'                from dual union all
    select 'E:\CD Drive   Someone Else   FileName_no_extension' from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(data_string, '(.*?)\s{3}', 1, 1, null, 1)              as filepath,
       regexp_substr(data_string, '(.*?)\s{3}', 1, 2, null, 1)              as username,
       regexp_substr(data_string, '(.*?\s{3}){2}(.*)(\.|$)', 1, 1, null, 2) as filename
from   inputs
;

FILEPATH     USERNAME         FILENAME               
------------ ---------------- ------------------------
C:\Desktop   JSchmoe          FileName                
E:\CD Drive  Someone Else     FileName_no_extension
```

**EDIT**:  It is possible that a filename contains more than one dot, for example `'report.march2017.pdf'`. In this case, only the last dot and what follows it must be stripped away. To handle this case, the search pattern for the third column must be modified. Here is one way:

```
with
  inputs ( data_string ) as (
    select 'C:\Desktop   JSchmoe   FileName.xml'                from dual union all
    select 'E:\CD Drive   Someone Else   FileName_no_extension' from dual union all
    select 'F:\SomeDrive   mathguy   File.dot.ext'              from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(data_string, '(.*?)\s{3}', 1, 1, null, 1)              as filepath,
       regexp_substr(data_string, '(.*?)\s{3}', 1, 2, null, 1)              as username,
       regexp_substr(data_string, '(.*?\s{3}){2}(.*?)(\.[^.]*)?$', 1, 1, null, 2) as filename
from   inputs
;

FILEPATH     USERNAME         FILENAME               
------------ ---------------- ------------------------
C:\Desktop   JSchmoe          FileName                
E:\CD Drive  Someone Else     FileName_no_extension  
F:\SomeDrive mathguy          File.dot
```

**EXPLANATION** of the `'(.*?\s{3}){2}(.*?)(\.[^.]*)?$'` search pattern:

- `.*?` matches any number of characters (zero or more), as few as
  needed while still allowing a match for the entire pattern.
- `\s` means one space; `\s{3}` means exactly three spaces.
- `(.*?\s{3}){2}` means two occurrences of (something, as short as possible, followed by three spaces). So this should bring us to the third "part" of the input.
- Now reading from the end of the pattern: `$` is the end-of-string anchor.
- `\.`is a single dot character. `[^.]` is any single **non**-dot character. `(\.[^.*]*)?` means: *optionally* (if possible) - that's the meaning of the question mark - one dot followed by zero or more non-dots. That would be the extension, anchored at the end of the string.
- There is just the `(.*)` left: zero or more characters, between the second occurrence of three spaces and the extension, if there is one - if not, the end of the string. This is exactly the filename, stripped of extension (if there is one) - and it is in the second set of parentheses in the entire match pattern, so we can refer to it as "2" in the last argument to REGEXP_SUBSTR.

Comment: What is '(.*?\s{3}){2}(.*?)(\.[^.]*)?$' doing?

Comment: @icerabbit - I added a detailed explanation (you are right - the pattern is a bit complicated and unusual, so the explanation may help others as well).

Comment: Thanks so much Mathguy. is there any way I can award two people best answers? I ended up using the other guys' solution and i feel really bad . Is there any way I can make sure you get credit as well (aside from upvoting which I already did)

Comment: @icerabbit - no worries, I don’t hold the rating system in high esteem anyway. Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks, glad to see people like you exist. Really appreciative of your consistent and constant help!